# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una agrupación en sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta. `SQL SERVER 2008`

```
SELECT a.id, b.Respuesta FROM users a INNER JOIN respuestas b
ON a.id = b.id
```

Eso me da este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero agrupar por el id de usuario pero cuando lo hago pierdo las respuestas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir para mi usuario 71 debería de contener todas sus respuestas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que puedo hacer un `join` por cada respuesta para tratarla como dato independiente. Pero no me gusta tener esta practica porque los `querys` pierden eficiencia.

Si tienen alguna idea o saben como hacer estas agrupaciones sin perder datos se los agradeceré.

Comment: en SQL Server hay una función para convertir las filas en columnas, tal vez es eso lo que necesites

Comment: Hola que versión de SQL Server tienes? 
Esto para saber que funciones se podrian utilizar.
Saludos

Comment: Hola, si se me paso mencionarlo. mi versión es antigua es 2008

Comment: al parecer la función si funciona en esa versión, la función se llama pivot, pero esta funcion te pone los datos en columnas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la función `STRING_AGG` de este modo para agrupar por renglón múltiples valores:

```
SELECT a.id, STRING_AGG(b.Respuesta, ',') AS Listado 
FROM users a 
INNER JOIN respuestas b
ON a.id = b.id
```

La función anterior es similar a `GROUP_CONCAT` de *MySQL* que sirve para concatenar múltiples valores en un solo renglón.

El segundo argumento que recibe dicha función es el símbolo que funcionará como separador de los valores y va entre comillas.

Comment: Desafortunadamente no puedo utilizar esta función en la versión de sql serve que tengo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes probar con esto
Simulo unas tablas para igualar la funcionalidad, espero sea lo que buscas y si no entiendes algo puedes preguntarme.
Saludos

```
--DECLARACIÓN DE SIMULACIÓN DE TABLAS
DECLARE @User TABLE (ID INT )
DECLARE @UserRespuesta TABLE (IDUser INT,Respuesta NVARCHAR(50) )

--INSERTAMOS VALORES PARA EL USUARIO 71
INSERT INTO @User VALUES(71)
INSERT INTO @UserRespuesta VALUES(71,10),(71,11),(71,12),(71,61),(71,41)
--INSERTAMOS VALORES PARA EL USUARIO 99
INSERT INTO @User VALUES(99)
INSERT INTO @UserRespuesta VALUES(99,55),(99,99)

--Esto es algo como lo que tienes
SELECT a.id, b.Respuesta FROM @User a 
INNER JOIN @UserRespuesta b
ON a.id = b.IDUser

--Esto es algo como lo que quisieras obtener
SELECT Us.ID,  STUFF((SELECT ', ' + A.Respuesta
FROM @UserRespuesta A
WHERE A.IDUser = Us.ID
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2, '')
FROM @User Us
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, pero no pude hacerlo con Stuff con este método, no me aparecen las respuestas.

Comment: Podrias mostrarme como lo estas haciendo?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes valerte de [`for xml`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) utilizando el modo [`path()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-path-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-2017) para concatenar los resultados, y la función [`stuff()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para eliminar la coma sobrante.

En código, simulando tus tablas con un CTE, sería algo así:

```
with
users as (
select *
  from (values (71)
             , (72)
       ) q (id)
)
,
respuestas as (
select *
  from (values (71, 28)
             , (71, 30)
             , (71, 29)
             , (71, 31)
             , (71, 32)
             , (71, 33)
             , (71, 40)
             , (71, 41)
             , (71, 34)
             , (71, 35)
             , (72, 1)
             , (72, 2)
             , (72, 3)
       ) q (id, respuesta)
)
select   users.id
       , stuff((select ',' + cast(respuesta as varchar(10)) from respuestas where respuestas.id = users.id for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') respuestas
  from users
```

Lo que devuelve:

```
id          respuestas
----------- --------------------------------------------------------
71          28,30,29,31,32,33,40,41,34,35
72          1,2,3

(2 rows affected)
```